Help with a Calculus exercise (indefinite integral)
I just started Calculus II, and up until now, I only did concrete examples, like integrals of actual functions, for example, $\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$. I was given the following exercise and am not sure how to approach it:
Let $g: I\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function with a continuous derivative, and invertible on the interval $I$, such that $g'(x)\neq0$ for all $x\in I$. Let $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function with anti-derivative $F$.
Show that $$\int \frac{f(g^{-1}(x))}{g'(g^{-1}(x))}\ \mathrm dx=F(g^{-1}(x))+C$$
I should note that the techniques we learned include:

Integration by parts
Integration of rational functions
Substitution method
Universal substitution method ($\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$)

Thanks in advance.

You say you have learnt the substitution method. Is there anything in this example that would be worth substituting to simplify the integrand?

Alternatively:  Do you know how indefinite integrals and derivatives relate?  (e.g. the fundamental theorem of calculus)  If so, there's another equation that is equivalent to yours but doesn't involve an integral...

Sadly we haven't yet learned about that theorem, only in 2 weeks :)

@BrianMoehring actually for indefinite integrals you don't need the FTC as they are defined as (equivalence classes of) antiderivatives, so you can differentiate both sides simply by virtue of the definition :)

See
$
\begin{align}
\mathcal {g} \left( \mathcal {g}^{- 1} \left( x \right) \right) & = x. \\
\mathcal {g}' \left( \mathcal {g}^{- 1} \left( x \right) \right) \cdot \left( \mathcal {g}^{- 1} \right)' \left( x \right) & = 1. \\
\left( \mathcal {g}^{- 1} \right)' \left( x \right) & = \frac {1}{\mathcal {g}' \left( \mathcal {g}^{- 1} \left( x \right) \right)}. \\ \\
\frac {1}{\mathcal {g}' \left( \mathcal {g}^{- 1} \left( x \right) \right)} & = \left( \mathcal {g}^{- 1} \right)' \left( x \right). \\
\frac {\mathcal {f} \left( \mathcal {g}^{- 1} \left( x \right) \right)}{\mathcal {g}' \left( \mathcal {g}^{- 1} \left( x \right) \right)} & = \mathcal {f} \left( \mathcal {g}^{- 1} \left( x \right) \right) \cdot \left( \mathcal {g}^{- 1} \right)' \left( x \right). \\
\int \frac {\mathcal {f} \left( \mathcal {g}^{- 1} \left( x \right) \right)}{\mathcal {g}' \left( \mathcal {g}^{- 1} \left( x \right) \right)} \text {d} x & = F \left( \mathcal {g}^{- 1} \left( x \right) \right) + C.
\end{align} \tag*{}
$

Thanks you, just seeing the first part gave me the idea to solve this.

You just need to show that
$$
(F(g^{-1}(x))'=\dfrac{f(g^{-1}(x))}{g'(g^{-1}(x))}.
$$
So, just compute the derivative on the left:
\begin{align*}
(F(g^{-1}(x)))'=& (g^{-1}(x))' F'(g^{-1}(x))=\frac{1}{g'(g^{-1}(x))}\cdot f(g^{-1}(x)).
\end{align*}

This is really the correct (simplest) solution. The other answers are unduly fixated on the idea that to prove an equality you must start with the left-hand side and somehow get to to the right-hand side.

Wow, haven't thought about that.

Let $g^{-1}(x)=h(x),\ \forall x\in I$ so that $g(h(x))=g(g^{-1}(x))=x$. Since $F(x)$ is the antiderivative of $f(x)$, $f(x)$ is the derivative of $F(x)$, i.e., $f(x)=F'(x)=\frac{\mathrm dF(x)}{\mathrm dx}$.
Now,
$$\begin{aligned}\int \frac{f(g^{-1}(x))}{g'(g^{-1}(x))}\ \mathrm dx&=\int \frac{F'(h(x))}{g'(h(x))}\ \mathrm dx\\&=\int \frac{\frac{\mathrm d(F(h(x)))}{\mathrm d(h(x))}}{\frac{\mathrm d (g(h(x)))}{\mathrm d(h(x))}}\ \mathrm dx\\&=\int \frac{\mathrm d(F(h(x)))}{\mathrm d(g(h(x)))}\mathrm dx\\&=\int \frac{\mathrm d(F(h(x)))}{\mathrm dx}\mathrm dx\\&=\int\mathrm d(F(h(x)))\\\int \frac{f(g^{-1}(x))}{g'(g^{-1}(x))}\ \mathrm dx&=F(g^{-1}(x))+C\qquad\text{proved.}\end{aligned}$$
Hope this helps!

Note that
$$1=(g\circ g^{-1})'(x)=g'(g^{-1}(x))(g^{-1})'(x)$$
by the definition of the inverse and the chain rule, so that
$$(g^{-1})'(x)=\frac{1}{g'(g^{-1}(x))}.$$
Then, substituting
$$u=g^{-1}(x),\quad \mathrm{d}u=(g^{-1})'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{g'(g^{-1}(x))}$$
we get that the integral becomes
$$\int\frac{f(g^{-1}(x))}{g'(g^{-1}(x))}\mathrm{d}x=\int f(u)\,\mathrm{d}u=F(u)+C=F(g^{-1}(x))+C$$
as desired.

In my opinion the Leibniz notation is more handy. Let $z=F(y)$ and $y=g^{-1}(x).$ Thus $x=g(y).$ The derivative of the right hand side is equal ${dz\over dx}.$ Next $f(g^{-1}(x))={dz\over dy}$ while $g'(g^{-1}(x))= {dx\over dy}.$ By the chain rule we have $\displaystyle{dz\over dx}={dz\over dy}{dy\over dx}.$
Hence
$${dz\over dx}={{dz\over dy}\over {dx\over dy}}$$ The left hand side is evaluated at $x$ while the numerator and the denominator are evaluated at $y=g^{-1}(x).$ This completes the proof.

It's a one-liner with the substitution $y=g^{-1}(x)$, whereby $x=g(y)$ and $dx=g'(y)\,dy$, so you get
$$
\int f(y)\,dy = F(y)+c
$$
Back substitute.
